# Can't access MySql DB from my Docker container with .Net API

Tags: mysql, .net, docker, api, ubuntu

on start i would like to say i'm new here and sorry if my question will be not precise.

Ubuntu 18.4 hosted on VPS,
MySql-server installed(not Docker) on same system where i run Docker with API.

Can't access MySql DB from my Docker container with .Net API.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["CVMakerAPI/CVMakerAPI.csproj", "CVMakerAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "CVMakerAPI/CVMakerAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/CVMakerAPI"
RUN dotnet build "CVMakerAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "CVMakerAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CVMakerAPI.dll"]
```

[In ConnecitonString I'm using user that have access to this DB][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHQey.png

[When I try to do some request i'm getting:][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXLFp.png

If more info needed please ask.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. On precision, you are pretty good. It generally helps if errors like your second image are included as text (you can edit the question after its posted). By the look at the stack trace its trying to DNS resolve what looks like an IP in your blatted out configuration. Are you sure its specified right? Also exposting mysql as a public port is a bad idea. Look at doing a SSH tunnel to your VPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside container we are in a different network space. So by default we do not have access to anything running in the host network. In this case MySQL.

By default all docker container uses the `Bridge` network mode. https://docs.docker.com/network/

> In terms of Docker, a bridge network uses a software bridge which allows containers connected to the same bridge network to communicate, while providing isolation from containers which are not connected to that bridge network. The Docker bridge driver automatically installs rules in the host machine so that containers on different bridge networks cannot communicate directly with each other.

So your container can not talk to the Mysql running on the host network.

To access the host network from container you can run you container in the host network namespace.

```
docker run --network host <your container>
```

https://docs.docker.com/network/host/